# How would you say "unlike" as the conjunction in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, conjunction

For instance, how would one say "*Unlike the physicians, Christian Scientists are not afraid to take the medication they prescribe to their patients by themselves.*" in Latin? In Croatian, you say "za razliku od" (for the difference from) for "unlike", so my attempt would be "*Pro differentia ab medicis, Christiani Scientistae non timent ipsi praehendere medicationes quae praescribunt suis patientibus.*"

Comment: Perhaps the word *dissimiliter* is worth looking into for related uses. At leas L&S lists it under *dissimilis*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such word. One would have to negate a normal conjunction (with a word like *contra*), or use a negative conjunction like nec. For example:

*quod contra consuetudinem puerorum, qui nascuntur et solent rubere, esset candidissimus, Albinus est dictus.* ("Unlike ordinary boys, who are born and usually are red, he was perfectly white, and so he was known as Albinus.") -- Historia Augusta

*Non enim, quemadmodum in palaestra qui taedas candentes accipit celerior est in cursu continuo quam ille qui tradit, item melior imperator novus qui accipit exercitum quam ille qui decedit.* ("Unlike what happens in the palaestra, where he who receives the flaming torch is swifter in the relay race than he who hands it on, the new general who receives command of an army is not superior to the general who retires from its command.") *Ad Herennium* 46.

*...contraria passus, quam Rhodano stimulatus Arar.* ("...unlike the flow of the Rhone, stimulated by the Saone.) --Claudian *Against Eutropius*

*at non sum, ita ut tu, gratiis.* ("But unlike you, I am not for free.") --Plautus *Persa* 285

*Igitur Latiaris iacere fortuitos primum sermones, mox laudare constantiam, quod non, ut ceteri, florentis domus amicus adflictam deseruisset.* ("Latiaris, therefore, began with casual remarks in conversation, then passed to eulogies on the constancy of Sabinus, who, unlike the rest, had not abandoned in its affliction the house to which he had been attached in its prosperity.") Tacitus *Annals* 4.58

*Non igitur ille ut plerique, sed isto modo ut tu, distincte graviter ornate.* ("Therefore, unlike most, he had a style that was as clear and cogent as your own.") Cicero, *De Natura Deorum*, I.59

These last three examples show how to express the idea from your example using *ut*:

*Physici Christiani non ut medici medicinam quam aegris suis suaserint sibi impavidi sumunt.*

In your own rendering, you do not need to say *Pro differentia ab medicis*, but rather just *ac contra medicos* (see Lewis & Short entry on *contra*, II.A.3).

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to rephrase slightly and use the verb *differre*. For example, you could do something like this:

> *Physici Christiani a medicis **eo differunt quod** non timent ipsis medicamentis uti quae  aegris praescribunt.*
>
> Christian Scientists differ from physicians in that they don't fear to use the very medications that they prescribe to the sick.

For *eo differre quod*, cf. Tactitus, *Germania* 44:

> forma navium eo differt quod utrimque prora paratam semper adpulsui frontem agit.

---

**Edit:** I have to say that I do also quite like *contra consuetudinem* + genitive, which is one of the options listed in Tyler's answer. One advantage of it is that it makes it easy to have an emphatic, obvious qualifying phrase at the beginning of the sentence, analogous to the 'unlike' phrase in English:

> *contra consuetudinem medicorum, physici Christiani non timent ipsis medicamentis uti quae aegris praescribunt.*
>
> Contrary to the normal practice of physicians, Christian Scientists don't fear....